# Llamar a un .py desde consola

Tags: python

```py
import os

def ver_ruta2(archivo2='pepe.txt'):

    ruta2 = os.getcwd()
    ruta = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'DATOS',archivo2)
     
    print(ruta2)
    print(ruta)
 
if __ name __ == '__ main __':

    ver_ruta2('pepe2.txt')
```

Cuando lo uso desde el intérprete de python funciona bien, tanto si le paso `'pepe2.txt'` o lo dejo vacío, pero si lo llamo desde la consola de Windows, no.

Siempre me muestra el archivo por default, y no sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es probable que en tu IDE tengas configurado un directorio de trabajo, pero cuando sales a DOS, quedas en otro. Revisa en que directorio está "pepe.txt".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el código que estás ejecutando es el que muestras en la pregunta, lo que debería mostrar siempre es `'pepe2.txt'` sin que importe lo que le estás pasando por línea de comandos. Si en la llamada dentro de "main" quitas `'pepe2.txt'`, entonces te mostrará siempre `'pepe.txt'` sin que importe lo que estés pasando por línea de comandos.

En ambos casos se debe a que tu programa *no está leyendo lo que le pasas por línea de comandos*.

El valor por defecto que asignas a la función se usa si cuando la llamas no le pasas parámetro, pero puesto que desde dentro de  "main" le estás pasando uno, pues mostrará siempre ese. Y el que le pasas desde "main" está prefijado en vez de ser leído de línea de comandos.

La solución, usar `sys.argv[]` para ver qué te estaán pasando por línea de comandos y actuar en consecuencia:

```py
import os
import sys

def ver_ruta2(archivo2='pepe.txt'):
    ruta2 = os.getcwd()
    ruta = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'DATOS',archivo2)
     
    print(ruta2)
    print(ruta)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv)==1:  # No nos están pasando nada por línea de comandos
        ver_ruta2()
    else:
        ver_ruta2(sys.argv[1])  # Usar el parámetro
```

Demo:

```
\Apps> python rutas.py
\Apps
\Apps\DATOS\pepe.txt

\Apps> python rutas.py hola.txt
\Apps
\Apps\DATOS\hola.txt
```

### Bonus: pathlib

Las versiones recientes de Python incluyen la librería `pathlib` que te da otra forma de trabajar con rutas y ficheros. En funcionalidad es equivalente a lo que puedes hacer con `os`, pero en sintaxis es más legible (aunque va en gustos) y sobre todo las funciones tienen una interfaz más uniforme.

Así que tu función se podría reescribir así usando `pathlib`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def ver_ruta2(archivo2='pepe.txt'):
    carpeta = Path(".")     # "." representa la carpeta actual
    ruta = carpeta / "DATOS" / archivo2
     
    print(carpeta.absolute())
    print(ruta.absolute())
```

Se llamaría igual que antes y produciría la misma salida.

Answer (score 0):

Los argumentos no se pasan entre comillas, el sólo hecho de escribirlos en consola llegan como string, proba con:

```
python rutas.py pepe22.txt
```

Comment: No estoy seguro de cómo funcione con pyhon, pero es probable que si querés que un parámetro tenga un espacio sí tengas que encerrarlo en comillas. Por ejemplo `python rutas.py pepe 22.txt` y `python rutas.py "pepe 22.txt"`

Comment: Esta respuesta no parece responder la pregunta.